# Name of an Exact Cover by 3 sets variant

Tags: terminology

Exact cover by 3-sets is $\sf{NP}$-complete:

> **Instance**: Given a finite set $X = \{ x_1,x_2,...,x_{3n}\}$ of $3n$ elements and a collection $C = \{ ( x_{i_1}, x_{i_2}, x_{i_3}) \}  $ of $m$ 3-elements subsets of $X$;
> **Question**: Find a subcollection $C'$ of $C$ such that every element in $X$ is contained in exactly one member of $C'$.

The problem remains NPC even if we add the following condition:

- every element of $X$ appears exactly in three subsets of $C$

Has this variant an "official" name?

Comment: It's similar to $3$-uniform hypergraph maximum matching. Perhaps in your case it is actually true that $i_1 \in \{1,\ldots,n\}$, $i_2 \in \{n+1,\ldots,2n\}$ and $i_3 \in \{2n+1,\ldots,3n\}$?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus: it is slightly more general: $i_j \in \{1,2,...,3n\}$.

Comment: It looks very similar to 1-in-3-SAT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Gonzalez](http://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~teo/papers/Ktmm.pdf) called this variant **RXC3**, for "Restricted Exact Cover by Three Sets."

Comment: thank you, I already saw it ... however if I don't receive other answers in 1-2 days I'll accept yours!